What is Tim Walz’s position on single-payer healthcare?
Minnesota Governor Tim Walz was just chosen as Vice President Harris’ running mate.  My question is, what is Walz’s position on single-payer healthcare?
I know he supported it in 2018.  Here’s what he said at the time in a statement to the Star Tribune:

Walz said in a statement that he also supports a longer-term shift to a single-payer system but a more immediate start of MinnesotaCare buy-in. "The rising cost of health care is crushing Minnesota families," Walz said in a statement. "We must take meaningful action to ensure every Minnesotan has access to high-quality, affordable health coverage."

But is 2018 the most recent time Walz spoke about his position?

TBH I'm not sure why you suspect he'd have changed positions, but I voted to reopen as the Q doesn't seem too much of a push on its face.

@timetakesitstoll Just because 2018 is a long time ago.
